# Counter-intuitive implication of Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma

Tags: linear-transformations, manifolds, euclidean-geometry

The Johnson Lindenstrauss Lemma (pasted below from a source) seems to me to have a strange implication.

[image]

Suppose I have two points (i.e. $n=2$) and I consider a very coarse error tolerance (e.g. $\varepsilon = 0.49)$. I think the missing constant obscured by $O()$ is 20, but this makes the following implication worse. The lemma says that there exists a linear map requiring $m = 0.49^{-2} \log(2) \approx 2.88 $ dimensions to preserve the distance between these two points. How does this make sense? Surely one dimension would suffice, no?

Comment: The constant makes this phenomenon worse. If you look at the wikipedia article, the constant is 8. That means we need > 20 dimensions for 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

The lemma says that such a map exists for the given value of $m$.  It does not say that you can't also get a map for a smaller value of $m$.  In other words, it makes no claim that the given value of $m$ is optimal.

Comment: This paper makes the claim that the given $m$ is optimal https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02094

Comment: Where does it claim that?  It proves a theorem related to the optimality but certainly does not assert that the given value of $m$ (for some particular choice of constant) is optimal for all possible values of $n$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Rylan: I didn't look at the paper, but what is probably meant is that *the scaling of m with n* is optimal as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think that's exactly what the paper asserts, if I understand it correctly

Comment: @PhoemueX I tried looking for the actual coefficients hidden by $\Omega$, but I couldn't find them. Can you?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer: The paper does not give an explicit constant though presumably one can be extracted from the proof with a lot of work.  In any case, there is certainly no reason to believe it's the _same_ constant as in the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma upper bound.